# replace() function not replacing backslash (\)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Non of following code is working ...

```
str = '\U0009d014'
print(str)

output:  

print(str.replace('\\',''))

output:  

print(str.split('\\'))
output:  ['\U0009d014']
```

I want to get string output but it's giving that unknown symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the raw string output:

```
s = '\U0009d014'
print(repr(s))
```

gives

```
'\U0009d014'
```

`s` is a unicode character (`\U` used for numbers in the highest range like `chr(1114111)`, you have `\u` for numbers in smaller ranges like `chr(57344)` and then ASCII in even smaller ranges like `chr(65)` that gives you the character `'A'`) in Python that's why printing it directly gives you an unknown character.

Also, don't use `str` as a variable. It's a built-in `<class 'str'>` in Python, you would overshadow this built-in with your variable that can cause issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're receiving a weird character in the output is because Python interprets your '\U0009d14' as a single unicode character.  When you print it, it's going to try to display the actual character, not the code you put in.  If you want it to operate like a string, you have to escape the backslash character at the beginning, like so:

`str = '\\U0009d014'`

This tells python to treat the backslash as the actual backslash character and not the beginning of a unicode character.

As other answerers have noted, you can also use `repr(s)` which gives you the string representation of a character.

An additional note: `str` is the `string` type in python and shouldn't be used as a variable name.  It will cause a lot of issues if you do so.  Consider `s` or a name more suited for the problem you're solving.